# Does iTunes Home Sharing transfer in-app purchases?

Tags: iphone, itunes, apple-id, home-sharing

My wife recently got an iPhone and, being that I'm an iPhone user already, I set up iTunes Home Sharing (under my Apple ID) so that I could share some of my purchased apps with her.

While paid apps transferred to her phone without a problem, in-app purchases that I had made under my account didn't transfer over.

Is this the correct behavior? Our phones are set up under different Apple IDs, but I was still able to transfer purchased (paid upfront) apps to her – which is completely allowed under the Terms of Use – so I assumed the same would apply to in-app purchases as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you must bear in mind that each In-App Purchase is uniquely associated with an Apple ID and that there are different *In-App Purchase* types:

- **Consumable** - You need to purchase these items every time you want them, and you can't download them again for free.
- **Non-Consumable** - You purchase these items one time, and you can transfer them to multiple devices authorized with the same iTunes Store account.
- **Non-renewing Subscriptions** - You can purchase these items again after the subscription period ends.
- **Auto-Renewable Subscriptions** - You can purchase these items with different renewal periods.

There are, therefore, differences in the way the availability of the *product* is handled.

As stated on Apple's [iTunes Store: About In-App Purchases](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4009):

> You **can't** sync or transfer **non-renewing subscriptions** and **consumable** In-App Purchase to another iOS device or Mac. You **can** transfer **non-consumable** In-App Purchases and **auto-renewable subscriptions** to another iOS device or Mac authorized with your iTunes Store account. For example, if you transfer a game from an iPhone to an iPod touch, only the game levels will sync, and the extra ammo and experience points won't transfer.

Comment: Thanks, that clears it up. The particular IAP in my question seems to be non-consumable (it's a one-time purchase that unlocks extra features in the app), but given that my wife's iPhone is set up under a different Apple ID, I guess that's why it doesn't transfer.

Answer (score 0):

I do believe that is a no, if you were to buy currency or items in a game, then those would be duplicated and cause possible errors. I think there may be a way in some apps to "claim" previous app purchases but I may be wrong.